# MatLab: Adding increasing data values in loop to cell

Tags: image, matlab, cell

I have a Loop which runs over a set of objects (from an image). These objects is used to calculate the area, perimeter, roundness and circularity of the objects in the picture. The program takes a batch of pictures and detects objects and computes these metrics. My problem is:

I can not save the data as matrix since each picture does not contain the some amount of pellets, i.e. the vectors containing area, perimeter and so on does not have the same length. So now I am trying with cells. But I can not get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
    %% Calculating metrics

for k = 1 : length(theFiles) 
  % loop over the boundaries
  for j = 1:obj2

  %Plotting boundaries
  boundary = B{j};
  plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1),'w','LineWidth',2)
  drawnow

  % obtain (X,Y) boundary coordinates corresponding to label 'j'
  boundary = B{j};

  % compute a simple estimate of the object's perimeter
  delta_sq = diff(boundary).^2;
  perimeter = sum(sqrt(sum(delta_sq,2)));
  perimeterD{k}(j)=[perimeter];

  % obtain the area calculation corresponding to label 'k'
  area = stats(j).Area;
  areaD{k}{j,1}=area;

  % compute the roundness metric
  metric = 4*pi*area/perimeter^2;
  metricD{k}{j,1}=metric;

  end
end
```

Where theFiles is the images analyzed.

The problem is, when running two images, I get a cell:

```
areaD = 

{40x1 cell}    {27x1 cell}
```

What I want is:

```
areaD =
[ 40x1 double] [ 27x1 double]
```

Or should I use a structure instead?

Cheers, 
Martin

Comment: well what you want is possible in cells only because matrix has to be of same length for all the columns but what you can do it save in a single structure  maybe that will be much easier , a strture can have different lengths of vectors

Comment: another benefit of storing into a structure would that you can store completely different types of data in a sam structure

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that. I did solve this, it works with cells now. But structure would maybe be better. Thanks!

Comment: areaD{k}(j,1) = area;